# Passing enum with multiple generic types as argument

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-protocols

I have the problem with Swift 2 - XCode Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x)

I have an enum State with two generic types. A function `printState` takes a State argument and prints "One" or "Two" based on the argument

```
protocol Protocol1 {
}

struct Struct1: Protocol1 {
}

protocol Protocol2 {
}

struct Struct2: Protocol2 {
}

enum State<T:Protocol1, U:Protocol2> {
  case One(firstStruct: T, secondStruct:U)
  case Two(secondStruct:U)
}

func printState<T:Protocol1, U:Protocol2>(state: State<T,U>) {
  switch state {
  case .One( _):
    print("One")
  case .Two( _):
    print("Two")
  }
}
```

When I call printState as below.

```
printState(State.One(firstStruct:Struct1(), secondStruct:Struct2()))
printState(State.Two(secondStruct:Struct2())) // This fails on compilation
```

I get a compilation error  on the second call to printState -

> error: cannot invoke 'Two' with an argument list of type
>   '(secondStruct: Struct2)'
>   printState(State.Two(secondStruct:Struct2()))

Everything works fine if T and U are constrained to class types. But I get this error only if T and U are protocol types. Also, I can get rid of this error by making case Two also accept a Protocol1, but it does not really need it.

Why am I getting this error? How can I make this work so that case Two only accepts Protocol1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the type of `T` since you only specify the type of `U`. Therefore you have to explicitly define the type:

```
printState(State<Struct1, Struct2>.Two(secondStruct:Struct2()))
```